# Finding the Conditional Expectation Estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

Let's say that the conditional PDF of random variables $\Omega$ and $Z$ is 
$$f_{\Omega\mid Z}(\omega\mid z)= \begin{cases} k\omega z, & 0 < \omega,z < 1, \\
0,& \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

For the PDF to be normalized, $k=4$.

Is the conditional expectation estimator of $Ω$ based on the observed value of $Z$ simply just $\int_0^1 w(4wz) \, dw=\frac{4z}{3}$? I want to know if my understanding on conditional expectation estimator is correct.

Comment: There is something wrong here. The conditional PDF must integrate to 1 (for each $z$), Then $k$ should be $2/z$ and the PDF does not depend on $z$. Also, I don't understand the bit about "For the PDF to be normal..."

Comment: I see. That explains why the conditional expectation estimator of Ω based on the observed value of Z is 2/3 and not $\frac{4z}{3}$. And I meant that "For the joint PDF to integrate to 1, k must be 4." Thank you very much, that answers the question.